# How to get width and height of view?

Tags: swiftui

I need to know the current view width and height, I managed to get it using the following code but it works only if I manually select the NavigationView.
I also tried to include the `GeometryReader { ... }` part in another view but it modifies the position of other elements.
My question to you, is there a way to call NavigationView automatically (just in order to get the view sizes) and return to the main view without manual action?
Or is there another way to get the current view width and height?

```
struct NavigationView : View {
    @ObservedObject var myMaze = Maze.sharedInstance
    var body : some View {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            Path { path in
                myMaze.viewWidth = geometry.size.width
                myMaze.viewHeight = geometry.size.height
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/60214735/12299030?

Comment: May be yes but where am I supposed to put the function rectReader?

Comment: @Swiftiti This may help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60726589/with-swiftui-is-there-a-way-to-constrain-a-views-size-to-another-non-sibling-v/62279021#62279021

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish, what is `Maze`?

Comment: Maze is a class for building a maze and I'm currently fighting with how to draw it on a view, you can see the 2 main files in https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1FK3eYbGmpLprgpqpLcpEDEFVHJ6cN8Gt?usp=sharing