# How do I align multiple views across multiple axes in SwiftUI?

Tags: layout, swiftui

How do I lay out the following in SwiftUI?

[image: Two vertically aligned circles with each circle having its own horizontally aligned rectangle]

The two circles are centre aligned horizontally along the blue line, and the top circle is vertically aligned with its rectangle along the green line, with the bottom circle vertically aligned with the bottom rectangle along the red line.

There’s no nested `HStack`/`VStack` structure that can describe this. We think the solution has something to do with [custom alignment guides](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/aligning-views-across-stacks), but all of the examples we could find stop short of this level of complexity.

Comment: Are the circles identically sized, as well as, are the rectangles identically sized?

Comment: You can get the center point in this way. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60726589/with-swiftui-is-there-a-way-to-constrain-a-views-size-to-another-non-sibling-v/62279021#62279021

Comment: @Yrb The circles are identically sized as it happens, but I feel that in the solution I’m looking for they shouldn’t need to be. In our particular case the rectangles aren’t identical, they’re `Text` views and we support dynamic type.

Comment: @Yodagama Stuffing sizes in preference keys and doing frame calculations on them is part of our current hacky solution and exactly what I’d like to avoid. SwiftUI is intended to be “declarative”, I should be able to declare that I intend this to be aligned with that, and then the computer works out the details.

Comment: Why the down/close vote?

Comment: I can tell you then that the answer is going to involve a combination of PrefKeys and AlignmentGuides. If you haven't seen [this from SwiftUI Lab](https://swiftui-lab.com/alignment-guides/) you should evaluate it. I am not sure how much more we can help as we don't have either the exact layout or your prior code to work with. I can tell you it is doable, and what you may have done may not actually be "hacky". While SwiftUI is declarative, it also handles layouts in certain ways, and you need to use things like pref keys to give it the info it needs to layout they way you want.

Answer (score 0):

It feels like your best bet in this situation would be to use a `LazyVGrid`. There's a tendency to think of grids being used for collections where we might have long lists of items, but they also work for a known, finite number of children, so I think they'd work here.

In essence, you have two columns of items – both can be flexible to a degree, but it sounds like your column of rectangles needs to expand more. So you could start off by trying something like:

```swift
let columns = [
  GridItem(.flexible(maximum: 120)), 
  GridItem(.flexible())
]

var body: some View {
  LazyVGrid(columns: columns) {
    // row 1, column 1
    RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10)
      .frame(width: 100, height: 160)
    // row 1, column 2
    Text("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque tincidunt enim in iaculis tincidunt. Nunc vitae imperdiet dolor")
    // row 2, column 1
    Circle()
      .frame(height: 100)
    // row 2, column 2
    Text("Integer vitae volutpat urna. Morbi vel pharetra dolor. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Mauris ornare a augue id cursus")
  }
}
```

The code above gives you something like:

[image: Visual appearance of above code]

I've not had the opportunity to use grids in this way myself yet, so haven't played around with all the customisation they offer, but it does feel like this might be the best way to get you what you want without worrying about alignment guides or preferences.

Comment: This was another approach we tried, but due to the intricacies of our actual design (the diagram above is a much simplified version) it meant cutting up the sub-views in the rectangles and re-assembling them in a different way which wasn't really satisfying. Good thought though.